# Add string from arguments to shared memory

Tags: memory, shared

I need to add to the shared memory string from arguments (ex. ./a.out abcxyz). I wrote the code, but it don't add string or don't show me string. What is the reason?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int shmid;
    char *buf;

        shmid = shmget(KEY, 5, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
        buf = (char *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

        *buf = argv[1];

    printf("\n%c\n",  buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're copying a string, so you can't just use assignment - you need [strcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy):

```
#include <string.h>

...


strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
```